# match value of one csv in another more complex csv

Tags: bash, csv, textmatching

This is unforunately on an Oracle OSS UNIX device that produces an error when I try using the following foreach command.

```
foreach x in File1 ; do grep $x File2.csv >> OUTPUT.csv ; done
bash: foreach: command not found
```

Here's what I'm working with:

```
File1
ABCD
EFGH
IJLK
...etc

File2.csv 
NODENAME,ABCD,PORTID,LONGNAME,NODEIP,WORKGROUP,etc...
...a whole lot of other entries that might/don't match... etc...

OUTPUT.csv <-- Final file.
```

I'm looking for (preferably BASH/CSH/KSH/PYTHON[noob]) command line that will one-by-one find/match line individual entries of File1 and output entire line from File2 into File3.  File2 is gigantic and I can single grep each of these entries from File1, but need to automate it.

REASON: I have a customer that on one technology (NODENAME) they can match their WORKGROUP, but the File2.csv does not contain WORKGROUP explanations that match, but the ABCD(CircuitID) might exist on more than one Technology platform. The output of each of these NODENAME entries were created as CSV and I was only able to pull matching WORKGROUP from one of the CSVs.
Thanks!!

Comment: Please, post a verifiable sample with the expected output and show something you have tried as this is not a free coding service.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: take a look at the `-f` option to `grep`